# Is there a way to do subqueries inside a case expression in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (v14)?

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm moving from PostgreSQL to SQL Server 2017 (v14) and need to rewrite some queries. One of the biggest (reduced down here) uses CASE statement with subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN (call_legs.to_phone_number NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT('1', phone_number)  
                                                    FROM directory 
                                                    WHERE description = 'OEM')) 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
        END) AS non_oem_out 
FROM 
    call_legs 
WHERE 
    leg_order = 0 
    AND type = 'Voice' 
    AND result != 'Blocked' 
    AND start_time >= '2022-10-09 12:00:00 AM' 
    AND start_time <= '2022-10-16 11:59:00 PM'
```

This works fine in  PostgreSQL but in SQL Server, I get an error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

My question: is there a way to do subqueries inside a `CASE` statement in SQL Server?

Comment: Just because it works in PostgreSQL doesn't mean it works on other databases or even that it's a good idea, either from a readability or performance perspective. This particular query will result in *very* bad performance because the database has to calculate `CONCAT('1',phone_number)` for all rows in `directory` before it can calculate whether `NOT IN` matches

Comment: Tbhe problem has *nothing* to do with the `CASE`, is the `SUM` that's the reason it's not working; you can't aggregate on subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct approach: Using a CTE to cover up for bad table design in table directory.

- Transform necessary lookup column to required format temporarily (first CTE part)
- Lookup from origin to CTE to decide to sum 1 or 0 value

Code Segment:

```
WITH
  cteDirectory
AS
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT( '1', phone_number ) AS to_phone_number
  FROM
    directory
  WHERE
    description = 'OEM' -- DO NOT USE reserved words!!!
)
SELECT 
  SUM( CASE WHEN dir.to_phone_number IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS non_oem_out 
FROM 
  call_legs AS cl
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cteDirectory AS dir
    ON  dir.to_phone_number = cl.to_phone_number
WHERE cl.leg_order = 0 
  AND cl.type = 'Voice' -- DO NOT USE reserved words!!!
  AND cl.result != 'Blocked' 
  AND cl.start_time >= '2022-10-09 12:00:00 AM' 
  AND cl.start_time <= '2022-10-16 11:59:00 PM'
```

Better approach is to add a derived column to table directory that executes the same deterministic function CONCAT. Then outer join both tables and do the same Case for calculation.